# Unable to deserialize Avro message using Confluent Schema Registry and Spring Cloud Stream

Tags: java, apache-kafka, avro, spring-cloud-stream, confluent-platform

I am using Spring Cloud Stream and Confluent Schema Registry to register Avro schemas.

Schemas are registered successfully. But when my Stream Listener receives a message the payload is still in Bytes.

Here are my properties.

> ```
> spring.cloud.stream.schemaRegistryClient.endpoint=http://localhost:8081
> spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.contentType=application/*+avro
> spring.cloud.stream.schema.avro.dynamic-schema-generation-enabled=true
> spring.cloud.stream.schemaRegistryClient.cached=true
> spring.cloud.stream.schema.avro.schemaLocations=classpath*:schemas/*.avsc
> spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.contentType=application/*+avro
> ```

While receiving message I noticed that "**convertFromInternal**" in "**AbstractAvroMessageConverter**" never gets invoked which is suppose to decode the message.

Answer (score 0):

What version of SCSt are you using? We fixed a couple of issues when integrating with confluent schema registry server on 1.3.

Also, you don't need to set the input contentType, resolution happens via headers that contain `application/vnd*+avro` that's the hint for the converter to kick in and find the correct schema from the server. You only set that contentType on the output channels, it gets replaced with the correct version for example: `application/vnd.user.v1+avro`

Comment: I am using SCSt 1.2.2.RELEASE. Do I need to upgrade?

Comment: There's an issue when fetching schemas from the registry, that was fixed on the 1.3 branch only. Another thing is how does your producer looks like? Try removing the input contentType definition as well, you should only rely on the headers

Comment: I tried removing the contentType for input but still having same issue. I have a simple producer with some headers  messageChannel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(request)
    .setHeader("retryCount", "0")
    .setHeader("createUserId", RequestContext.getCurrentContext().getUserId()))
    .build());  Is there a release scheduled for 1.3?

Comment: I just tried using spring-cloud-stream-schema-server instead of confluent schema registry, but the message is still in Bytes. It doesn't seem like an issue with confluent specifically.

Comment: Please open an issue with as much information as you can, add the source for your producer, along with the configuration files, as well as the consumer and we will investigate.